# How to disable logs while running Android CTS tests

Tags: android, adb, cts

When I run Android certification tests(tradefed) tests from a Linux machine, I see logs coming on the screen continuously. How can I disable it?

For example:
These logs are for tvts tests:

06-07 15:57:48 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    0     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:   12     Last Test#:    0
06-07 15:57:59 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    1     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:   11     Last Test#:    3 Passed
06-07 15:58:18 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    2     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:   10     Last Test#:    4 Passed
06-07 15:58:38 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    3     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:    9     Last Test#:    5 Passed
06-07 15:58:48 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    4     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:    8     Last Test#:    6 Passed
06-07 15:59:08 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    5     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:    7     Last Test#:   10 Passed
06-07 15:59:19 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    6     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:    6     Last Test#:   11 Passed
06-07 15:59:38 D/YtTestHeartBeat: Total:   12     Passed:    7     Failed:    0     Optionally Failed:    0     To Run:    5     Last Test#:   18 Passed

I want to trigger this test from Python code. After executing 'run tvts-cert' command, if I execute 'list invocations', python code also reads these logs in addition to response of 'list invocations'. I want to disable it, so that it only returns me the response of executed command. I tried using --log-level-display/-l <log_level> argument. But it didn't disable these logs.

Comment: Try to define your problem clearly. If possible  quote some example logs, attach picture if needed.